# How to select data from 3 drop down lists and display results on text boxes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, aspxcombobox

I have 3 drop down lists, and I need to select data from these dropdown lists and display results on text boxes instead of a Grid. On selectedIndexChange of the last drop down I would like to populate the data on text boxes. e.g display minimum and maximum on text boxes.

This is the last drop down i need selectedOndexChanged when selecting

```
protected void ddlPaperLevel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
e)
    {
        try
        {
            lblError.Text = "";
            string paperlevel = ddlPaperLevel.Text.Trim();

            DataTable specs = new DataTable();

            if ((specs = WIP.GetLabSpecs()).Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < specs.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)        //Fluting 125 Special
                    {
                        txtFlut125gsmN.Text = specs.Rows[i]
   ["GramageMin"].ToString().Trim();
                        txtFlut125gsmX.Text = specs.Rows[i]
   ["GramageMax"].ToString().Trim();
                        txtFlut125MoistN.Text = specs.Rows[i]
   ["MoistMin"].ToString().Trim();
                        txtFlut125MoistX.Text = specs.Rows[i]
   ["MoistMax"].ToString().Trim();
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "instead of a grid"? Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: sorry I will post my code. I mean I do not want to display in a table but in text boxes.

Comment: What are you expecting of us to do? Write all the code for you? You need to make your question more direct and show us what code you have (tried). But here is how i would do it: Just save the first two values of the dropdown boxes in a variable and when the last dropdown box is selected, check if the first two values aren't empty and then write the values to the text boxes.

Comment: @Svenmarim I have edited and put my code thanks

Comment: @IrishChieftain I have edited and put my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easly write code for you result

```
protected void dropdownlist3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string strddlText1 = Convert.ToString(dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text);
     string strddlText2 = Convert.ToString(dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Text);
     string strddlText3 = Convert.ToString(dropdownlist3.SelectedItem.Text);
     if(strddlText1 != "" && strddlText2 != "" && strddlText3 != "")
     {
       Textbox1.Text = strddlText1 + " " + strddlText2  + " " + strddlText3;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this out

Comment: are you passing that 3 dropdown list value in any method to fetch data from database ?

Comment: Yes @Y.M.Mnu... exactly how you say it. Thanks. So what I'm doing is select the 3 drop down lists, i already created tables where i fetch them. and based on the combination of the choices from 3 dropdowns I would like to display info to text boxes (Min, Max etc..) but display on the last drop down selection... i tried my code is not working maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: match your data type where you are passing them, debug you code.

Comment: **paperlevel** where are you using this variable i can't understand ?

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox1.text=
    DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text+
    DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text+
    DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text+(and So on);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much... I am actually fetching data from the database based on the 3 selections from the 3 drop down lists. its displaying and clearing to the textboxes that am struggling with. my dropdown items are ok they are showing perfectly but its on selection of the dropdown that am struggling on

Answer (score 0):

Save the values in a variable and when the last dropdown box is selected, take all the values and put them in the textbox with:

```
Texbox1.Text = "valuesFromDropdown"
```

Comment: Thankyou @Svenmarim let me try that

Comment: Thankyou everyone my dropdowns are now displaying to textboxes